# Angular 11 compilation stuck on “Generating browser application bundles (phase: building)”

Tags: angular, compiler-errors, angular11

Tried replacing all code files with older ones which were working but nothing helped
[This is what's happening](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QjYuF.png)

Anybody able to overcome this??

Comment: Whenever I experience this I cancel the current operation `CTRL + C` and rerun the command

Comment: Wow, you lucky!